# TestFlight show crashes but no reports

Tags: ios, crash-reports, testflight

I have an app ready for App Store which I've also distributed for test in TestFlight.

TestFlight is registering crashes, but when I want to see the reports, there is none! It used to work, but I cant seem to figure out why there is none.

My app is targeting iOS7, built in iOS8 SDK and I've updated TestFlight SDK and uploaded crash dSYM.

[image: Screen dump of TestFlight]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're still on the old testflight like me.  My crash reports have disappeared as well.  I'm reading this as Apple starting to turn off the lights on the old one and push people to the iTunesConnect version.  On my team we're looking at using Crashlytics for crash reporting and HockeyApp down the line for beta distribution.

P.S. I've also heard rumors on Twitter of apps being rejected because they include the TestFlightSDK in them.  For now you can remove the sdk and still do the binary uploads.  At least until Apple pulls the plug on that too.

Update:  I just received an email from Apple that TestFlightApp.com will no longer be available after Feb. 26 2015.

Comment: That seems like a plausible answer. It is annoying that I dont get crash reports in the new TestFlight instead.